# I can't display the vue-chart.js on the page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, diagram, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to learn how to use vue-chart.js and Chart.js .
The problem is that on the Main page.vue does not display the graph itself

here is the code from ../src/Chart/RandomChart.vue

```
<template>
    <div>               
        <random-chart></random-chart>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import RandomChart from '../Chart/RandomChart.vue'
export default{
    components:{
        RandomChart
    }

}
</script>
```

here is the code from ..src/Chart/LineChart.js

```
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

export default {
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ['options'],
  mounted () {
    // this.chartData создаётся внутри миксина.
    // Если вы хотите передать опции, создайте локальный объект options
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
  }
}
```

here is the code from RandomChart.vue although it is also in the official documentation

```
<template>
  <div class="small">
    <line-chart :chart-data="datacollection"></line-chart>
    <button @click="fillData()">Randomize</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import LineChart from './LineChart.js'

  export default {
    components: {
      LineChart
    },
    data () {
      return {
        datacollection: null
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      this.fillData()
    },
    methods: {
      fillData () {
        this.datacollection = {
          labels: [this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt()],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'Data One',
              backgroundColor: '#f87979',
              data: [this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt()]
            }, {
              label: 'Data One',
              backgroundColor: '#f87979',
              data: [this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt()]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      getRandomInt () {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 5 + 1)) + 5
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
  .small {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin:  150px auto;
  }
</style>
```

well, the code from App.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="app">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        
    }
</script>
<style scoped>
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
```

and main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from "@/router/router";



const app = createApp(App)

app
    .use(router)
    .mount('#app');
```

and json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-chart-3": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.1",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.11",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
```

I've been sitting for a long time and I don't understand what the problem is, maybe there's a stupid mistake that I don't see.

Answer (score 0):

vue-chartjs is not compatible with chart.js v3 (latest version) so you will need to downgrade chart.js to version 2.9.4 to make it work or you need to use chart.js barebone without the vue wrapper:

```sh
npm uninstall chart.js
npm install chart.js@2.9.4
```

Comment: like in vue.js can I use a diagram, js without a vue diagram? I've been trying to add a graph to Main for 2 days, but by zeros

Comment: I dont understand what you mean with vue diagram but if you want to use the vue wrapper for chart.js you will need to downgrade chart.js to v2, otherwise you can ditch the vue wrapper and just use chart.js barebone as you would do in a default js script and then you can use v3

Comment: So, then how do I use (char.js ) in my app?


Here, for example, is the diagram I want to take
https://apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/pie-charts/simple-pie-chart/

how do I load it into Main as a page element.

Tell me please

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/usage.html

Comment: `
<template>
 <div>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
 <div>
</template>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {.....})
</script>
`
Like this? And then import it into Main.vue?